# I want to remove an html div automatically while the Landing page runs

Tags: javascript, slider, marketo

I have made this Landing page: https://study.navitas.com/griffith-mature-age-lp.html

If you look at the testimonial slider, you will see it has one extra blank slide.

I used Display none to hide that slide through CSS. But since the code is being pushed through js (owl slider) it still shows that as a blank slide.

How can i remove the slide without modifying the HTML code? I can not modify the HTML template as it is being used for other pages as well, where we have 3 slides. The template has been created in Marketo.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you'll just need to add a bit of extra JavaScript in the LP's head (under the Edit Meta Tags section). The landing page uses Owl Carousel, so we just need to interact with it like so:

`var owlCarousel = jQuery(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');
owlCarousel.removeItem(2);`

This removes the third, blank slide and lets the page just interact with the two that have data.